# Installing gettext in windows :Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed

Tags: django, gettext

I followed the instructor of installing gettext on windows and when I type xgettext --version in my command prompt it says that it has installed. but when I want to run this command: python manage.py makemessages -l "fa"
in my project it says Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.
I tried so hard but it seems there are no good answers out there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In windows you just need to download :

```
gettext-tools-xx.zip
gettext-runtime-xx.zip
```

from here:
  [enter link description here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies/)

and then you need to unzip them and copy all in bin folder of both files into C:\Program Files\gettext-utils\bin
and then you need to go to control panel-> system -> advanced -> environment variables and add this path:C:\Program Files\gettext-utils\bin to path variables.
Note:

- xx is the version you want to download if you download version 18
  you will get an error that some dll file is missing, I suggest to
  download version 17
- this folder :gettext-utils\bin does not exist and you need to create
  it
- resteart your pc before you use gettext

Answer (score 6):

on windows7/windows10 you have to download gettext-iconv-windows , try the following url:

https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html

after you download it  and install it , close and reopen your CMD , and then try to use your command again .

i hope this helpful

Comment: This does also work on Windows 10. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for your comment , i have update my answer .

Comment: This is better and most recent answer!